# Call Function Upon Document Ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to start polling a URL upon the page loading, to get a JMS response from a credit card server.  I put the following together.

It works, but only if I hit the Refresh button on the browser.  I want the data from the URL to load  automatically when the page is first displayed, without requiring the user to Refresh.

I am missing a fundamental concept here, and would appreciate any advice on how to make it work. I have about 2 days of JavaScript experience so far.

```
<html>
    <body>

        <div id="p_results"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                function doJMSPolling() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "./poll",
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "text",
                        success: function(json) {

                            var json = $.parseJSON(json);

                            if (json.status === 'continue-polling' && json.msg === 'ok') {
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    doPolling();
                                }, 2000);
                            }
                            else if (json.status === 'stop-polling' && json.msg === 'success') {
                                for (key in json) {
                                    if (key === "providerResponse") {
                                        res = json[key];
                                        for (reskey in res) {
                                            $("#p_results").append(reskey + ":" + res[reskey] + "<br>"); 
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            } else if (json.status === 'stop-polling') {
                                $("#p_results").text(json.status);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to place the actual function definition inside your `document.ready` callback. The function can sit anywhere inside the `<script>` tags. Once you have done that, all you need to do is call the function from within the `document.ready` callback -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  doJMSPolling();
});

function doJMSPolling(){
 ...
}
</script>
```

---

Note :

`$(function(){})` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){})`

Comment: Dang, beat me by a 50 seconds :). I blame indenting that **huge** function LOL.

Comment: @mat - hehe... Well I figure that the actual contents of the function is irrelevant and that pseudo code can easily convey the idea :)

Comment: **Absolutely**, I just got fixated on using the actual code :). +1 for beating me!

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me that you're declaring your function, but not calling it. In order for the function's code to execute you'll need to add this after the function declaration within document.ready:

```
doJMSPolling();
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't put your function **within** the `document.ready`, simply **call it** in there. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    doJMSPolling();
});

function doJMSPolling() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "./poll",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(json) {
            var json = $.parseJSON(json);
            if (json.status === 'continue-polling' && json.msg === 'ok') {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    doPolling();
                }, 2000);
            }
            else if (json.status === 'stop-polling' && json.msg === 'success') {
                for (key in json) {
                    if (key === "providerResponse") {
                        res = json[key];
                        for (reskey in res) {
                            $("#p_results").append(reskey + ":" + res[reskey] + "<br>"); 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (json.status === 'stop-polling') {
                $("#p_results").text(json.status);
            }
       }
  });
}
```